# How Can I Covert Server Timestamp To Normal Time Using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, datetime

The response is

```
{serverTime: 1549037445885}
 serverTime: 1549037445885
```

I want to covert this in to normal Time.If It Contains date and Time,Can I Store Time Only In H:M:S Format In To Another Variable
How can i do it in JAVASCRIPT?

Comment: There are plenty of resources about the Date object, [read them first](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and if you're having issues then come back with a proper [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).

```
const moment = require('moment')

moment(new Date(1549037445885)).format('h:mm:ss')
```

or you can use the builtin JS

```
let date = new Date(1549037445885),
    hours = date.getUTCHours(),
    minutes = date.getUTCMinutes(),
    seconds = date.getUTCSeconds(),
    formatedTime = `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`
```

Assuming you want UTC time. If you want local time just leave the UTC off each method call.